# How to find an application installation path directory with java

Tags: java, path, installation

I have installed my jar application using packjacket, an installer generator.http://packjacket.sourceforge.net/

default installation path will be in "../program files/myapp.jar"

but how can java language detect different installation path if user decide to change to different path directory during installation. (currently i just hard code the default location as C:/../program files/)

i have read this question, [How to find an application installation path in the ms windows registry via EXE name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472172/how-to-find-an-application-installation-path-in-the-ms-windows-registry-via-exe?lq=1). But regrettably still not understand.

ps: im not sure if my jar application have registry path or not because i rely on packjacket installer to install my apps.

this reference is unclear:
[find the path of my application installed in registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231903/find-the-path-of-my-application-installed-in-registry)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear.

Your application should never make assumptions about where it might be stored and should rely on relative paths or know variable paths, such as the user's home directory (`System.getProperty("user.home")`).

You can find you current "working" directory using `System.getProperty("user.dir")`